# Using python to network layer 2 packets through vpn

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, vpn, scapy

I don't have any code at the minute - I'm more reaching out for ideas at the min.

**scenario**
I have a software vpn (radmin/ dynvpn, zerotier one) that I use to create a layer 3 tunnel between remote laptops.

The endpoint laptop has routing enabled in windows which allows me to connect to siemens plcs remotely.

This largely works very well, however certain features that rely on layer 2 protocols dont work remotely.

**goals**
Id like to pack the relevant layer 2 protocols into some layer 3 packet using python running on both sides.
Then obviously have the opposite end unpack the packets.

Im fairly new to python (6months) but am doing ok with intermediate type stuff.

Im going to be looking into scapy, but wandered if anyone had further ideas/ insights.

Thanks

Comment: This is way too broad to provide a meaningful answer and will likely be flagged/closed. "certain features that rely on layer 2 protocols" => expand. "I don't have any code at the minute" => what should the code do pretending you were using an arbitrary libarry? "Id like to pack the relevant layer 2 protocols" => which ones?

Comment: There are 2 protocols - one is arp which is obviously well known. The other is a siemens proprietary protocol.  I dont really have further details of the siemens one until I get chance to get wireshark running at site